# Xcode using retina images for all devices

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, image, retina

I have following images on my XCode project.

```
appstore~iphone.png
appstore@2x~iphone.png
appstore~ipad.png
appstore@2x~ipad.png
```

But whenever I use an image as appstore.png, only retina images (2x) are being used.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

I am using XCode 6.0.1 (6A317)
Thanks.

Comment: I think you need to test on a non-retina device for the non-retina assets to be loaded.

Comment: Ensure, that you use `imageNamed:` method, check `[UIScreen mainScreen].scale` in debug (it should be 2 for retina).